# Why crystal report required parameter again when print/export

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, crystal-reports

Dear all I am working on an asp .net application (Webform) in which I am using crystal report for showing reports (with store procedure ).

In my application everything works fine including the reports. The real problem comes when I start clicking on the crystal report toolbar. If I click on any buttons on the crystal report tool bar like (Export, next page ...etc.) it is asking parameters again. Is there any way so that that the crystal report viewer does not ask the parameter that I have already given ?

```
 ReportDocument r = new ReportDocument();
                r.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Consumers/Reports/JobOrder.rpt"));
                SqlParameter[] para= new SqlParameter[1];
                para[0]= new SqlParameter("@OrderId",JobOrder);
                dt=da.ExecuteQuery("sp_rpt_JobOrder",para);
                if(dt.Rows.Count>0)
                {
                    r.SetParameterValue("@OrderId", JobOrder);
                    r.SetDataSource(dt);
                    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = r;
                }
```

can some one help me? Highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

its causing due to post back. so i removed

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
```

now its working fine for me.

Thank you.